# Invalid syntax error near '<' when using case when variable, works fine without variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, syntax, operators

I am trying to resolve this SQL issue where my code throws an error

> Invalid syntax error near '<'

when I use the variable `@totalprice`. Without using the variable, the `CASE` works and the query executes correctly but I want it as a variable

Thanks

```
Declare @totalprice int
Select 
Case @totalprice
      when "Age" < 2 THEN [Price(RM)]+100 
      when "Age" > 2 AND "Age" <= 11 THEN [Price(RM)]+200
      when "Age" > 11 AND "Age" <= 17 THEN [Price(RM)]+300
      when "Age" > 17 AND "Age" <= 64 THEN [Price(RM)]+500
      when "Age" >= 65 THEN [Price(RM)]+200
END AS Total_Price
From Reservation
```

Comment: What are you trying to **do** *in plain english*? EDIT are you trying to set `@totalprice`? You need `SET @totalprice = CASE ...`

Comment: Why are you using the variable `@totalprice` there? `CASE` has 2 formats - one where all cases are compared against the value right after `CASE` (@totalprice) and another where no value is placed after `CASE` and instead each `WHEN` is evaluated as a boolean. You have both types mixed.

Comment: Also you may get multiple results from the table, you can't assign all of them to one variable

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, "Age" is a column that I have so assuming if age inserted is below two, the data inserted for price column will be added with 100 and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign the result of the `CASE` expression to your variable - use this code:

````
DECLARE @totalprice int

SELECT
    @totalprice = CASE
                     WHEN Age < 2 THEN [Price(RM)] + 100 
                     WHEN Age > 2 AND Age <= 11 THEN [Price(RM)] + 200
                     WHEN Age > 11 AND Age <= 17 THEN [Price(RM)] + 300
                     WHEN Age > 17 AND Age <= 64 THEN [Price(RM)] + 500
                     WHEN Age >= 65 THEN [Price(RM)] + 200
                  END 
FROM
    Reservation
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try this, plus bonus bug removal!

```
declare @totalprice int

select @totalprice = [Price(RM)] + case
  when Age < 2 then 100 
  when Age <= 11 then 200
  when Age <= 17 then 300
  when Age <= 64 then 500
  else 200
end as Total_Price
from Reservation
```

Note the simplification by removing the repetitive `[Price(RM)]` and removing redundant lower bounds of ranges - `when` are evaluated top down with the first matching condition used.

You have a bug: If the value is `2`, none of your `when` conditions are met, so the result will be `null`. This refactoring takes care of this bug too.

Comment: This works but I want to use a variable so that I can use that variable with my insert statement for the Total_Price column instead of using END AS

Comment: @NathanS I see. Amended to save to variable, plus discovered and fixed a bug in your logic.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right then you want to set the result of your query into @totalprice parameter. You can achieve that by below query:

```
Declare @totalprice int
Select @totalprice=
Case 
      when "Age" < 2 THEN [Price(RM)]+100 
      when "Age" > 2 AND "Age" <= 11 THEN [Price(RM)]+200
      when "Age" > 11 AND "Age" <= 17 THEN [Price(RM)]+300
      when "Age" > 17 AND "Age" <= 64 THEN [Price(RM)]+500
      when "Age" >= 65 THEN [Price(RM)]+200
END 
From Reservation
```

But no matter how many rows you have in the table you will get the last record's value only.